# Why is this code block not running?

Tags: java, for-loop, ascii

I am making a diamond using ASCII art. Yes, I know the code is beyond sloppy. Anyways, the last part is not running inside of an else block, leaving the diamond not finished.
Full code:
http://pastebin.com/14HnZADe

Current output:

http://pastebin.com/YTqKrRQe

The for loop:

```
 for(int i = 1; i<=size; i++) {
     for(int j=1; j<=size; j++) {
         if(j<i) {
             System.out.print(" ");
         }
         else if(j==i || j>i) {
             System.out.print("*");
         } else {//this block is not executing, and I do not know why.
             for(int ki = 1; ki<=size; ki++) { // how do I fix it?
                 for(int n = size; n>=1; n--) {
                     if(j>=i) {
                         System.out.print("*");
                     } else {
                         System.out.print(" ");
                     }
                 }
             System.out.println();
             }
         }
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
```

Comment: This is not a 'debug my code for free' service!!! There's a question-closing category designated specifically for your type of question, called "why isn't this code working?".

Comment: Please post your code here...

Comment: @brso05 He does not need to, because it will get closed soon.

Comment: Please post your code here, rather then link to it.

Comment: @MuratK. it's not a bad question he should post his code here though...I'm not voting to close it. There is nothing wrong with his question.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: If an `else` block doesn't execute, then clearly a preceding `if` condition evaluated to `true` and *that* block executed.  Step through the code in a debugger to observe this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your conditions has to be met before it gets to the `else` block:

```
if(j<i) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
else if(j==i || j>i) {
```

`j` is either less than `i` or greater than `i` or equal to `i`. You have specified all possible conditions therefore the `else` will never execute...

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
if (j<i) {
    //..
} else if (j==i || j>i) {
    // ..
} else {
    // this will never happen
}
```

But `j==i || j>i` is the same as `j>=i`. The else block will never execute because j will always be either smaller than i or greater than or equal to i. There are no other options!